# How to convert UTC timestamp to device local time in android

Tags: android, timestamp, utc

I need to convert the UTC time stamp that I get from the server to local device time. Currently, I get 5 hrs difference in my time. For example, when I post to the server, the post time says 5 hours ago instead of a second ago. How could I fix this issue?

Below is the code that I do:

```
long timestamp = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
            CharSequence relTime = DateUtils
                    .getRelativeTimeSpanString(timestamp * 1000
                            + TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset(),
                            System.currentTimeMillis(),
                            DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);
            ((TextView) view).setText(relTime);
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The code in your example looks fine at first glance. BTW, if the server timestamp is in UTC (i.e. it's an epoch timestamp) then you should not have to apply the current timezone offset. In other words if the server timestamp is in UTC then you can simply get the difference between the server timestamp and the system time (`System.currentTimeMillis()`) as the system time is in UTC (epoch).

I would check that the timestamp coming from your server is what you expect. If the timestamp from the server does not convert into the date you expect (in the local timezone) then the difference between the timestamp and the current system time will not be what you expect.

Use `Calendar` to get the current timezone. Initialize a `SimpleDateFormatter` with the current timezone; then log the server timestamp and verify if it's the date you expect:

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();

/* debug: is it local time? */
Log.d("Time zone: ", tz.getDisplayName());

/* date formatter in local timezone */
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
sdf.setTimeZone(tz);

/* print your timestamp and double check it's the date you expect */
long timestamp = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
String localTime = sdf.format(new Date(timestamp * 1000)); // I assume your timestamp is in seconds and you're converting to milliseconds?
Log.d("Time: ", localTime);
```

If the server time that is printed *is not* what you expect then your server time is *not* in UTC.

If the server time that is printed is the date that you expect then you should not have to apply the rawoffset to it. So your code would be simpler (minus all the debug logging):

```
long timestamp = cursor.getLong(columnIndex);
Log.d("Server time: ", timestamp);

/* log the device timezone */
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
Log.d("Time zone: ", tz.getDisplayName());

/* log the system time */
Log.d("System time: ", System.currentTimeMillis());

CharSequence relTime = DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(
    timestamp * 1000,
    System.currentTimeMillis(),
    DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS);

((TextView) view).setText(relTime);
```

Comment: thanks @pestrella that gives me a formatted time format but i want to show time like 2 min ago, 1 hour ago .. using the android utils. any workaround for that ....thanks

Comment: Your code example looks good to me and that should give you the time difference (e.g. 2 min ago). However, I don't believe you should have to apply the rawoffset to the server time (assuming that the server time is in UTC). I need more information to help. As per my code example, did you print the server time, and is it the time you expect?

Comment: yes ur code gives me the time in standard format,, but i want to show the time like 17 mins ago....

Comment: pestrella My code gives me what i expect, but the time difference is 5 hrs. any idea

Comment: Out of curiosity what is the server timestamp that you are working with? Also, if you change DateUtils.MINUTE_IN_MILLIS to 0 then you will get the elapsed time in seconds (e.g. 2 seconds ago). Could you do another test using 0 instead of MINUTE_IN_MILLIS? Log the server timestamp. What timestamp did you get? and what did your TextView display?

Comment: the server time i get in string format is in UTC when i tried your code i got something like 14/02/2013 16:50:16 and when i changed DateUtils.minute_in_millis to 0 i got in 4 hours and 20 hours ago and with Minute_in_mills i get 5 hrs ago

Comment: In that case either: 1. your device is in GMT+4, or 2. the server is returning UTC timestamps in the future, or 3. your server is not actually return UTC timestamps. In order to help debug the issue, I would log the server timestamp (the Long not the String formatted date), and also log the System.currentTimeMillis() (again the Long value). I would additionally log the device timezone (cal.getTimeZone().getDisplayName). I will update the code above to contain the required logging.

Comment: Hi, What is "cursos" variable here?

Comment: Hi @danny, the [`cursor`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/Cursor.html) object is not essential for the solution. It is used by the OP to read data from the database; in this case the timestamp is being read from the database.

Comment: For show time as Just Now or xx min ago or xx days etc. use this: https://github.com/curioustechizen/android-ago

Answer (score 73):

**Java:**

```java
int offset = TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() + TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings();
long now = System.currentTimeMillis() - offset;
```

**Kotlin:**

```kotlin
val offset: Int = TimeZone.getDefault().rawOffset + TimeZone.getDefault().dstSavings
val now: Long = System.currentTimeMillis() - offset
```

Comment: To also account for daylight savings: int gmtOffset =  TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset() + TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings();

Comment: This should be the answer.

Comment: I noticed that this approach doesn't take into account the daylight savings. @FarshidT answer covers this short-coming but I think that the less verbose of achieving the same is by using
`int utcOffset = Timezone.getDefault.getOffset(System.currentTimeMillis())`

Comment: should not it be minus in here? `long now = System.currentTimeMillis() - gmtOffset`

Comment: Sorry, this answer is not correct. Milliseconds since the epoch are always since the epoch. Adjusting them for time zone and/or summer time (DST) does not make sense. If you code ends up giving you the correct result, it has still gone the wrong way there and will be sure to confuse future readers.

Comment: A mixture of pestrella's answer and this worked for me.

Answer (score 56):

**Converting a date String of the format "2011-06-23T15:11:32" to our time zone.**

```
private String getDate(String ourDate)
{
    try
    {
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Date value = formatter.parse(ourDate);

        SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm"); //this format changeable
        dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
        ourDate = dateFormatter.format(value);

        //Log.d("ourDate", ourDate);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        ourDate = "00-00-0000 00:00";
    }
  return ourDate;
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer on the whole SO. Thank you!

Comment: Does this take care of daylight savings as well?

Comment: This works perfect. But suppose i m trying convert 2018-04-27 12:48:00 UTC time zone to IST time zone. Now here it return after convert   2018-04-27 06:18:00 am instead of 2018-04-27 06:18:00 pm what to do in this scenario? Here if any UTC time come between 12:00:00 to 12:59:59. this return wrong result. In other work perfect.

Comment: @madhusudhan how to convert this one 2018-12-01T20:21:36.793194+05:30

Answer (score 9):

I did it using `Extension Functions` in `kotlin`

```
fun String.toDate(dateFormat: String = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", timeZone: TimeZone = TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC")): Date {
    val parser = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault())
    parser.timeZone = timeZone
    return parser.parse(this)
}

fun Date.formatTo(dateFormat: String, timeZone: TimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault()): String {
    val formatter = SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat, Locale.getDefault())
    formatter.timeZone = timeZone
    return formatter.format(this)
}
```

Usage:

```
"2018-09-10 22:01:00".toDate().formatTo("dd MMM yyyy")

Output: "11 Sep 2018"
```

Note:

Ensure the proper validation.

Answer (score 3):

I have do something like this to get date in local device timezone from UTC time stamp.

```
private long UTC_TIMEZONE=1470960000;
private String OUTPUT_DATE_FORMATE="dd-MM-yyyy - hh:mm a"

getDateFromUTCTimestamp(UTC_TIMEZONE,OUTPUT_DATE_FORMATE);
```

**Here is the function**

```
 public String getDateFromUTCTimestamp(long mTimestamp, String mDateFormate) {
        String date = null;
        try {
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            cal.setTimeInMillis(mTimestamp * 1000L);
            date = DateFormat.format(mDateFormate, cal.getTimeInMillis()).toString();

            SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(mDateFormate);
            formatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
            Date value = formatter.parse(date);

            SimpleDateFormat dateFormatter = new SimpleDateFormat(mDateFormate);
            dateFormatter.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault());
            date = dateFormatter.format(value);
            return date;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return date;
    }
```

**Result :**

```
12-08-2016 - 04:30 PM
```

Hope this will work for others.

Comment: DateFormat.format is imported from which package ? Is it java.text.DateFormat ?

Answer (score 3):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // A sample timestamp as Unix epoch (i.e. seconds from 01-01-1970T00:00:00 GMT)
        long epochSeconds = 1632131465L;

        // Note: Use Instant#ofEpochMilli in case you have timestamp in milliseconds
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(epochSeconds);
        System.out.println(instant);

        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.systemDefault());
        System.out.println(ldt);
    }
}
```

**Output in my timezone, Europe/London:**

```
2021-09-20T09:51:05Z
2021-09-20T10:51:05
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/lrWsdu)

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline, normally represented in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc) time. The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for a zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Local to UTC

```
DateTime dateTimeNew = new DateTime(date.getTime(),
DateTimeZone.forID("Asia/Calcutta"));
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
String datetimeString = dateTimeNew.toString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
long milis = 0;
try {
     milis = simpleDateFormat.parse(datetimeString).getTime();
} catch (ParseException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer from @prgDevelop returns 0 on my Android Marsmallow. Must return 7200000. These changes make it work fine:

```
int offset = TimeZone.getTimeZone(Time.getCurrentTimezone()).getRawOffset() + TimeZone.getTimeZone(Time.getCurrentTimezone()).getDSTSavings();
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help some one with same requirement

```
private String getDate(long time){
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm a");
        String dateString = formatter.format(new Date(time));
        String date = ""+dateString;
        return date;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Simply set your utc timestamp to your timezone calendar and format the date. Timestamp is still the same no matter timezone.

```
val local = Calendar.getInstance()   // get your device timezone calendar
local.timeInMillis = <timestamp>

val sdf = SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
val formatted = sdf.format(Date(local.timeInMillis))
```