# Converting UTC timestamp to local device timestamp

Tags: java, android, timestamp

For some reason I always have the hardest time with getting timestamps to display correctly but anyway here is my problem.

I am pulling events from the `Calendar Provider API` and some events such as the `US Holidays` calendar events are in UTC so the timestamp is not what it should be on the device (unless the device is in that timezone of course).

I have a timestamp of this `1374105600000` which is `07/18/2013 00:00:00 UTC` so july 18th at midnight UTC. What I want is the timestamp of july 18th at midnight local device time.

This is what I do

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = cal.getTimeZone();
cal.setTimeInMillis(time);

long offset = tz.getRawOffset(); //gives me -18000000 5hr difference since I am in EST which I think is actually wrong because it should be a 4hr difference now with DST
```

So if I add this to the UTC timestamp

```
long local = time+offset;
```

it gives me the incorrect time `july 17th at 3:00PM`

If I subtract the times

```
long local = time-offset;
```

I still get the wrong time, it gives me `july 18th at 1:00AM` but I dont think I should even be subtracting because that wont work for people in `+` timezone differences.

What am I doing wrong, why can I not get the correct offset to get the correct time?

I was also using this like as reference too [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853389/how-to-convert-utc-timestamp-to-device-local-time-in-android)

Answer (score 2):

Since Java `does not` ATTACH the `Timezone` information with a `Date` object, its a little weird to do the conversion. Please check below listing, where I am trying to convert the time from "UTC" (GMT) to "EST" (can be New York's timezone)

```
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class TimeZoneTest {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Calendar gmtTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        Calendar estTime = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
        
        System.out.println(getInputDate() + " (Actually GMT)");
        estTime.setTime(getInputDate());
        
        gmtTime.clear();
        gmtTime.set(estTime.get(Calendar.YEAR), estTime.get(Calendar.MONTH), 
                estTime.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), estTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY), estTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        gmtTime.set(Calendar.SECOND, estTime.get(Calendar.SECOND));
        Date estDate = gmtTime.getTime();
        System.out.println(estDate + "(Actually EST)");
    }
    
    private static Date getInputDate() {
        Calendar instance = Calendar.getInstance();
        instance.clear();
        instance.set(2014, 3, 2, 9, 0, 0);
        Date input = instance.getTime();
        return input;
    }

}
```

And the output is

```
Wed Apr 02 09:00:00 IST 2014 (Actually GMT)
Wed Apr 02 05:00:00 IST 2014(Actually EST)
```

which is actually [correct](http://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/converted.html?iso=20130402T09&p1=0&p2=179)

**EDIT**: Its important to use "America/New_York" instead of "EST" to consider Day light Saving

Answer (score 0):

hmmm.. the code below reverses your scenario , but maybe u can make use of it??

```
private  Date cvtToGmt( Date date )
{
   TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
   Date ret = new Date( date.getTime() - tz.getRawOffset() );

   // if we are now in DST, back off by the delta.  Note that we are checking the GMT date, this is the KEY.
   if ( tz.inDaylightTime( ret ))
   {
      Date dstDate = new Date( ret.getTime() - tz.getDSTSavings() );

      // check to make sure we have not crossed back into standard time
      // this happens when we are on the cusp of DST (7pm the day before the change for PDT)
      if ( tz.inDaylightTime( dstDate ))
      {
         ret = dstDate;
      }
   }

   return ret;
}
```