# Convert W3C TimeZone to device TimeZone android

Tags: java, android, database, timezone, w3c

**What I have**

I have a date string from server which is in **w3c date format 2016-02-13T09:53:49.871Z**

**My problem**

When I post the message to the server , it shows 5 hrs before instead of just now

**What I want**

I wanted the server `TimeZone` to be converted to the device `TimeZone` , so that irrespective of the region , the user will see his local time format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it , If any one needs can refer this code

```
public String convertW3CTODeviceTimeZone(String strDate) throws Exception {
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormatW3C = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", Locale.US);
        simpleDateFormatW3C.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        Date dateServer = simpleDateFormatW3C.parse(strDate);

        TimeZone deviceTimeZone = TimeZone.getDefault();
        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        simpleDateFormat.setTimeZone(deviceTimeZone);

        String formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(dateServer);
        return formattedDate;
    }
```

Comment: "W3C" is not a valid zone identifier. You are just lucky that in this case, Android will silently fall back to GMT. So use "GMT" instead (for correct interpretation of trailing Z in your input).

Comment: 2016-08-26T00:00:00+00:00

how to convert this? having "+00:00"

Answer (score 0):

Hope this blogspot and link what you expecting:

http://javagrip.blogspot.in/2012/09/date-from-one-timezone-to-another-in-java.html

[How to convert UTC timestamp to device local time in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853389/how-to-convert-utc-timestamp-to-device-local-time-in-android)