# Timestamp to Date/Time

Tags: android, datetime

I am trying to make a football Livescore app. And I need to show the match time to users as their local match time.
if I was generated a Timestamp from a given timezone, lets say it is

```
autodatetime(1517009400,6.5); //original timezone included    
//I can make it done in javascript by https://www.autodatetime.com/
```

But I was trying to get it from Android with this code

```
public String getconvertedtime(long timestamp) {
    try{

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),Integer.toString(TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings()),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        //getTimezonedifference() return 0 for me
        timestamp= timestamp-getTimezonedifference();
        calendar.setTimeInMillis(timestamp * 1000);
        calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, (tz.getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis())-tz.getDSTSavings()));
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss aa");
        Date currentTimeZone = calendar.getTime();
        return dateFormat.format(currentTimeZone);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        return "";
    }

}
public int getTimezonedifference() {

    TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Calendar cal = GregorianCalendar.getInstance(tz);
    double offsetInMillis = tz.getOffset(cal.getTimeInMillis());
    //String offset = String.format("%02d:%02d", Math.abs(offsetInMillis / 3600000), Math.abs((offsetInMillis / 60000) % 60));
    //offset = "GMT"+(offsetInMillis >= 0 ? "+" : "-") + offset;
    offsetInMillis= Math.abs((offsetInMillis)-(6.5*3600000));
    int vall=(int)offsetInMillis;
    return vall;
}
```

Unfortunately It was returning wrong time, I can't figure it out why it was showing faster hours .
The result is **01/27/2018 12:30:00 PM**
It must be **01/26/2018 11:30:00 PM** for my Local TimeZone(6.5)

And I found something about different DST problems from googling and get 0 from *"TimeZone.getDefault().getDSTSavings()"* on Toast.

Please guide me to the solution, I am new to android programming. Thank you for reading.

Comment: May be this link will help you to solve your problem.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853389/how-to-convert-utc-timestamp-to-device-local-time-in-android

Comment: is this time `1517009400` in UTC or your local time zone?

Comment: Maybe also take a look at JodaTime http://www.joda.org/joda-time/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Given epoch of `1517009400`, which is `01/26/2018 23:30:00 GMT`, to show this time in user's local time:

```
// convert to epoch milli seconds
long ts = 1517009400000l;
Date date = new Date(ts);

DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
String dateStr = dateFormat.format(date);

android.util.Log.i("TEST", "dateStr: " + dateStr);
```

`dateStr` will be formatted according to timezone of user's phone. For example, my phone is set to `Asia/Kuala_Lumpur` timezone, which is `GMT+8`, so it shows `01/27/2018 07:30:00`.

To format date string into particular timezone (eg: New York), you can try this:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
format.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("America/New_York"));
String dateStr = dateFormat.format(date);
```

This outputs `01/26/2018 18:30:00`.