# Firebase ServerTimestamp applies same timestamp for every country?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

does firebase **servertimestamp** applies same time session for every country which is generated by firebase server for example ...if an app is controlled from one nation then will the server applies that countries timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

> Will the server applies that countries timestamp?

No, as explained in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) (Firestore documentation but it is the same with a RTDB [`TIMESTAMP`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.ServerValue.html#timestamp)):

> A Timestamp represents a point in time **independent of any time zone** or
>   calendar, represented as seconds and fractions of seconds at
>   nanosecond resolution in UTC Epoch time.

If you want to display the value according to the local time for a specific "nation" (i.e. time zone), it is up to you derive it from the UTC value. See, for example: [How to convert UTC timestamp to device local time in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853389/how-to-convert-utc-timestamp-to-device-local-time-in-android/32480192)