# Convert UTC time recieved from weather api to local time

Tags: android, timezone, json-api-response-converter

I am calling current weather API response from 
https://openweathermap.org/current

The API response has sunset and sunrise value like this :
"sunrise": 1560343627, "sunset": 1560396563
The parameter unit is written as Sunset time, Unix, UTC

I know the location and now I want to convert this time to the local time of the place. How can I do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert UTC timestamp to device local time in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14853389/how-to-convert-utc-timestamp-to-device-local-time-in-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For converting timestamp to current time

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
calendar.add(Calendar.MILLISECOND, tz.getOffset(calendar.getTimeInMillis()));
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", Locale.getDefault());
java.util.Date currenTimeZone=new java.util.Date((long)1379487711*1000);
Toast.makeText(TimeStampChkActivity.this, sdf.format(currenTimeZone), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Hope it will work

Thankew! Happy coding!

Comment: These terrible date-time classes are now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Answer (score 3):

Use *java.time* classes.

```
int millisSinceEpoch = Integer.parseInt( "1560343627" ) ;
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( millisSinceEpoch ) ;
```

That `Instant` object represents a moment as seen in UTC. You can adjust to a time zone to see that same moment through the wall-clock time used by the people of a certain region.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Pacific/Auckland" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String covertUnixToHour(int sunrise){
    Date date = new Date(sunrise* 1000L);
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    String formatted = sdf.format(date);
    return formatted;
}
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.